# How to make a js object from an object array?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
[
   { name: H, value1: 10, value2: 40},
   { name: W, value1: 20, value2: 50},
   { name: S, value1: 30, value2: 60}
]
```

I need:

```
{
h: {value1: 10, value2: 40},
w: {value1: 20, value2: 50},
s: {value1: 30, value2: 60},
}
```

Sorry for the stupid question. I'm a student.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```js
function getObj(arr) {
   return arr.reduce((p,next)=> {
      const {name, ...left} = next;
      p[name]=left;
      return p;
   }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let test = [
    { name: 'H', value1: 10, value2: 40},
    { name: 'W', value1: 20, value2: 50},
    { name: 'S', value1: 30, value2: 60}
]
let test2 = {}
test.forEach(v => {
    test2[v.name] = v
    delete test2[v.name].name
})
```

Comment: FWIW I think this answer is the best one since it doesn't use `reduce` (all other 5 (so far) do).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
   { name: "H", value1: 10, value2: 40},
   { name: "W", value1: 20, value2: 50},
   { name: "S", value1: 30, value2: 60}
]

const obj = arr.reduce((o,item) => {
 const key = item.name
 delete item.name
 o[key] = {...item}
 return o
},{});

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```js
const data = [
   { name: 'H', value1: 10, value2: 40},
   { name:'W', value1: 20, value2: 50},
   { name: 'S', value1: 30, value2: 60}
]

const result = data.reduce((res, {name, ...rest}) => {
  res[name.toLowerCase()] = rest
  return res
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
  { name: "H", value1: 10, value2: 40 },
  { name: "W", value1: 20, value2: 50 },
  { name: "S", value1: 30, value2: 60 },
];

const output = input.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const { name, ...rest } = currentValue;

  return {
    ...accumulator,
    [name.toLowerCase()]: rest,
  };
}, {});

// {
//   h: { value1: 10, value2: 40 },
//   w: { value1: 20, value2: 50 },
//   s: { value1: 30, value2: 60 },
// };
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function array2object(array, key = 'name') {
  return array.reduce((object, element) => ({ ...object, [element[key]]: (() => { delete element[key]; return element })() }), {});
}

const result = array2object(
  [
    { name: 'H', value1: 10, value2: 40 },
    { name: 'W', value1: 20, value2: 50 },
    { name: 'S', value1: 30, value2: 60 }
  ]
);

console.log(result);
```